# Bootstrap Carousel not scroll bug

Tags: html, slider, carousel

for some time, my image slider no longer scrolls the images remains stuck on the first image while there are 3 which are supposed to scroll, at the beginning it worked and today nothing more
my goal is to scroll through the images in the carousels every 5 seconds, do you have a solution?

here my code

```
 <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
      </div>
      <div class="col-12">
      <div class="row">
  <div class="container">
  <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="../img/fond5.png" alt="First slide">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h2>text</h2>
          <p>text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
    <img class ="d-block w-100" src="../img/camera4.jpg" alt="...">
    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
      <h2>text</h2>
      <p>texte</p>
    </div>
    
  </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="../img/camera3.jpg" alt="Third slide">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Make a reproducible example, pls.

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/#with-controls :)